# How to get the value of Variable from a Promise in Node.js

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to figure out, how to get this promise to a variable outside the scope.

```
var picture = JSON.stringify(this);
s.search('danbooru', { tags: ['cat'], limit: 1, random: true })
.then(images => console.log(images[0].common.fileURL))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I can't find any possible soluton!

Comment: If the variable is defined outside of your functions scope (eg a global variable) you still have access to it and can save the results to the variable as you normally would (inside the `then` block, just go with `yourVariable = images[0].common.fileURL`.).

Comment: `.then(images => variableInOuterScope = images)`

Answer (score -1):

if `s.search()` returns a Promise, you sure can assign that Promise to a variable:

```
const searchPromise = s.search('danbooru', { tags: ['cat'], limit: 1, random: true });

searchpromise.then(images => console.log(images[0].common.fileURL))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

That would have its benefits (you can reuse the promise later). However, that is assigning a **Promise** to a variable, not the result of the promise:

if, instead, you want to assing **the search result** to a variable, you could do something like:

```
let images = null;

s.search('danbooru', { tags: ['cat'], limit: 1, random: true })
.then( img => {
    images = img;
})
.catch( ... )
```

However, you need to be sure that you will only access the `images` variable when the promise is settled:

**bad:**

```
let images = null;

s.search('danbooru', { tags: ['cat'], limit: 1, random: true })
.then( img => {
    images = img;
})
.catch( ... )

console.log(images); //bad, images will be null at this point.
```

**fine:**

```
let images = null;

s.search('danbooru', { tags: ['cat'], limit: 1, random: true })
    .then(img => {
        images = img;
        return anotherPromise();
    })
    .then(someResult => {
        console.log(someResult);
        console.log(images); //fine, images is guaranteed to be properly set at this point
    })
    .catch(... )
```

However, declaring mutable variables and assing them at some point in a promise chain could lead to issues. This [really good SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain) assess the problem of reusing promise values and I'm pretty sure it will be useful to your issue.

Comment: Why would you want to return `anotherPromise` in the first place? If it's about receiving a promise at some end, you could simply return the original promise, no?

Comment: Well, sometimes, in a promise chain, you need to reuse the value of a previous promise in another promise call. Like, you first grab an `user`, then you grab something that needs the user -lets say a `cardId`-, then you grab a third thing that needs both the user and the `cardId`: in such situation you would need to store the user in a variable. The code in my answer was only an example of a situation in which you can safely access the `images`var, doesn't pretend to be useful.

Answer (score -1):

> how to get this promise to a variable outside the scope.

Don't. Use. Outside-scope. Variables.

Promises are about *returning* things. Return the promise chain. Return the values you want to work with. Work with them in the `.then()` callbacks.

Do not use global variables. Do not do work outside the promise chain.

```
function search(params) {
    return s.search('danbooru', params)
        .then(images => {
            /* do something with images[0].common.fileURL */
            return images;
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

search({ tags: ['cat'], limit: 1, random: true }).then(images => {
    /* do something else with images[0].common.fileURL */
});
```

What you *can* do is store and re-use the promise itself.

```
var result = search({ tags: ['cat'], limit: 1, random: true });

/* ... do some things ... */

result.then(images => { /* do something with images */ });

/* ... do other things ... */

result.then(images => { /* do another thing with images */ });
```